# 2 different materials on one object with texture paint?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, texture-painting

I'm not totally sure if this is possible but I am trying to make a toon shaded model of Spider-man while keeping the poly count low by using two materials on the same object with texture paint.

Basically, here is my red material:
[image: red material]

and here is my blue material:
[image: blue material]

I want to be able to paint this blue material over the red material so I can keep these shadows and highlights and to keep the blue shinier.

I've tried regular texture painting where the whole object is one material and I paint on the blue as a base color, but it didn't have the look I wanted with the highlights and shadows.

Is it possible to have both colors on the same object while maintaining these highlights and shadows?

I'd really appreciate any help! Stack Exchange has never steered me wrong!

(also right now my plan for the webbing is to stencil paint them on with a PNG, so if anyone has any better ideas than that, it would be greatly appreciated!)